# Newly created node type is always disabled

Tags: 7, installation

I have created a new node type using a custom module on Drupal 7. However when I check the content type under the structure menu item it isn't listed. Looking in the node_type table, I see that it is listed as disabled. My question is how do I get the content type to be enabled?

Here is my content type creation function located in mymodule.install file:

```
// define the node type
  $type = array(
    'type' => $machine_name,
    'name' => $t($parameters['name']),
    'base' => 'room_reservations',
    'module' => 'room_reservations',
    'description' => $t($parameters['description']),
    'has_title' => TRUE,
    'title_label' => $t($parameters['title_label']),
    'custom' => FALSE,
    'locked' => TRUE,
    'disabled' => FALSE,
  );

// set other node defaults not declared above
  $content_type = node_type_set_defaults($type);

// add the body field
  node_add_body_field($content_type, $t($parameters['body_label']));

// save the content type
  node_type_save($content_type);
```

I believe this is correct but it obviously doesn't work. Any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal base install uses this configuration to create the `basic page` content type. Try to modify the `custom` value just like the example underneath:

```
$type = array(
    'type' => 'page',
    'name' => st('Basic page'),
    'base' => 'node_content',
    'description' => st("Use <em>basic pages</em> for your static content, such as an 'About us' page."),
    'custom' => true,
    'locked' => true,
    'modified' => true,
    'disabled' => false,
);
```

**Edit**

I've just checked the code of some Drupal core modules how they manage the creation of content types within code.

The `Blog` module defines the content type within the `HOOK_node_info` (just like you did). This to notify Drupal about the new type. The `HOOK_install` only add fields to the content type. The module also implement the `HOOK_form` for the content creation form and `HOOK_view` for the rendering.

```
// blog.install
function blog_install() {
  // Ensure the blog node type is available.
  node_types_rebuild();
  $types = node_type_get_types();
  node_add_body_field($types['blog']);
}

// blog.module
function blog_node_info() {
  return array(
    'blog' => array(
      'name' => t('Blog entry'),
      'base' => 'blog',
      'description' => t('Use for multi-user blogs. Every user gets a personal blog.'),
    )
  );
}
```

}

Comment: The custom value indicates whether the content type was create by a module or by a user. In my case, setting it to false is the correct thing to do.

Comment: If you are still interested, I've updated my answer with the correct implementation for custom content types in code.

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer to my own question. I believe that along with using hook_install() you must also use hook_node_info() as well. I was under the impression from reading the documentation that when adding fields to your node type, all you needed to do was use hook_install() as shown in the original question. That didn't work for me. It did work when I included hook_node_info() and that seemed to make the node types enabled. Am I correct that you have to use both these hooks in order to get custom node types to display?